# Split elements by \n inside a list

Tags: python, list, split

I have this list:

```
test_results = ['Test1\nTest2', 'Grade A\nGrade B']
```

I want to split the elements by the '\n' and save them in another list, like this:

```
test_results = [['Test 1, Grade A'], ['Test B', 'Grade B']]
```

I am struggling to find a way to do it... can you help me?

Comment: what have you tried ?

Comment: `test_results = [i.split('\n') for i in test_results]` would be a starting point.  You also probably want to look at `zip` for rotating the resulting list of lists.

Comment: This (at least the 1st part of it) can be achieved in one line using https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` with `str.splitlines`

```py
>>> x = list(map(str.splitlines, test_results))
>>> x
[['Test1', 'Test2'], ['Grade A', 'Grade B']]
```

Now you can use `zip` to get what you exactly want:

```py
>>> [[a,b] for a,b in zip(x[0], x[1])]
[['Test1', 'Grade A'], ['Test2', 'Grade B']]
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I did not take close look to that, I'll update the answer

Comment: @ChihebNexus, I think it matches the expected output now

Answer (score 1):

You could use splitlines.

```
y = [x.splitlines() for x in test_results]
```

output

```
[['Test1', 'Test2'], ['Grade A', 'Grade B']]
```

Comment: PO is searching for this output: `[['Test 1, Grade A'], ['Test B', 'Grade B']]`

Comment: That's for sure a typo. Why would user want that?

Answer (score 0):

There are many 1-liners, but this might be the easiest to understand

```
def split_list(list):
    for string in list:  # For each string in my list
        list[list.index(string)] = string.split(
            "\n")  # Splitting the string a "\n"

    return test_results


test_results = ['Test1\nTest2', 'Grade A\nGrade B']
print(split_list(test_results))
```

Comment: Your output is wrong. PO is searching for this output: `[['Test 1, Grade A'], ['Test B', 'Grade B']]`